# zoneminder on 13.10 cannot click on add new monitor

Tags: 13.10, zoneminder

I've installed zoneminder on 13.10, however, when I access the browser interface (localhost/zm) I cannot click on "add new monitor". It's like this feature is disabled or something. When I click on "add new monitor", nothing happens. Absolutely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iconnor/zoneminder
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/iconnor-zoneminder-saucy.list
```

change 'saucy' to 'precise', ctrl-o to save, ctrl-x to exit

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zoneminder
```

select 'I' to overwrite existing file and 'y' to convert tables to InnoDB

Comment: [http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_12.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.26.4_the_easy_way](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_12.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.26.4_the_easy_way)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Ubuntu 14.04 ZoneMinder v1.27.1) I solved it:

instead of

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iconnor/zoneminder
```

I used this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iconnor/zoneminder-master
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you need to disable option 'OPT_USE_AUTH' in 'Options --> System'. After that, restart ZoneMinder and Bingo!