# Zoneminder on 14.04 cannot click on Add new monitor

Tags: zoneminder

After I installed ZoneMinder, some functions do not seem to work such as  *Add New Monitor*.

I tried this solution:

[zoneminder on 13.10 cannot click on add new monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432577/zoneminder-on-13-10-cannot-click-on-add-new-monitor),

but this does not work as you can see on this forum [discussion](http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=583001).

This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zoneminder/+bug/806101) might be related, but looks like it's already fixed...

Answer (score 2):

You must enable common javascript directory in apache configuration:

```
sudo a2enconf javascript-common
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! (ZoneMinder, v1.27.1)
With the help of the [forum](http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=583001) and the [source](https://launchpad.net/~iconnor/+archive/ubuntu/zoneminder-master/+packages):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iconnor/zoneminder-master
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

ZoneMinder currently does not work on 13.10 or newer, due to mysql support in PHP being deprecated. Version 1.28 will hopefully work on 13.10 and up when it is released.

Therefore please install ZoneMinder 1.26.5 available in Ubuntu Software Center.
Please refer to [How to install Zoneminder](http://bkjaya.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/how-to-install-zoneminder-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit/).

Comment: With this guide and your guide, the virtual machine (virtualbox Ubuntu 14.04, Zoneminder v1.26.5) works! 
With the same guide on the real machine (Ubuntu 14.04, Zoneminder v1.26.5), it gives me problems (example: Add new monitor) :( . Instead, for example, the button (Refresh), (Option) work!

Comment: Before re installation  you will have to uninstall zoneminder completely .Please refer http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/z/zoneminder/en/uninstall/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your user tab in your settings: If a user is restricted to specific monitors, then they will not be allowed to add new monitors.  Only users who are not restricted to a camera are allowed to add new monitors.

If you are logged in as a user with restriction to specific monitors, then you will need to logout and login to a user with no restriction.  Hope that helps.